# Multiple Requests Using Task.WhenAll()

Tags: c#, performance-testing

I am trying to stress test my WebApi that is uploaded onto Azure. Specifically this test is for logging into an app. I decided to make a mock client using c# and create a list of Tasks, each of which will send the same request to my WebApi. My problem is that it throws an exception after using more than 300 tasks.

The Exception: "Thread has been Cancelled"
Inner exception: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."
Code where exception occurs: await (Task.WhenAll(tasks));

Am I doing something wrong in my test code? If so, what? And how to I correct the error? Thanks!

Notes:
-I have tried running the test code against the API locally

-The API code is surrounded by a try catch block and when running the test code against it, it did not hit my breakpoint set in the catch block and an exception was still thrown in the test code.

-Since this is a project at work, I have replaced real log in credentials and the URL to the API with stand-ins

below is my test code

```
public static async Task<decimal> LoginTestParallel3Async(){
    Stopwatch timer = new Stopwatch();
    var tasks = new List<Task>();
    LoginRequestModel request = new LoginRequestModel();

    int numOfRequests = 500;

    decimal totalTimeForTasks = 0;
    string jsonObject = "";

    request.UserName = "User";
    request.Password = "Password";
    request.UserId = 0;

    jsonObject = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(request);

    try
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < numOfRequests; i++)
            {
                //tasks.Add(client.PostAsync("URLForAzure", new StringContent(jsonObject, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")));
                tasks.Add(client.PostAsync("URLForLocal", new StringContent(jsonObject, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")));
            }

            timer.Start();
            await (Task.WhenAll(tasks));
            timer.Stop();
            totalTimeForTasks = timer.ElapsedMilliseconds;

            Console.WriteLine("total time for request: " + totalTimeForTasks + " milliseconds");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message.ToString());
        return totalTimeForTasks;
    }

    return totalTimeForTasks;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation the value of `MaxConnectionsPerServer` property from `HttpClient` is 256 by default. So in order to achieve what you need, you have to change this value to a larger number.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclienthandler.maxconnectionsperserver?view=netcore-2.0#System_Net_Http_HttpClientHandler_MaxConnectionsPerServer

ex.
`var client = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler { MaxConnectionsPerServer = 1000 });`

Comment: This is the new error message I am getting after replacing my using statement with the statement you provided: e.Message
"An error occurred while sending the request."
e.InnerException.Message
"Unable to connect to the remote server"

Comment: Well, this exception sounds like a firewall or network issue. I don't see how can it be related to this setting.

Comment: Or you may be facing a blocking due to an excessive amount of requests to the server.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the insight. I changed the code so that I have 4 separate clients, each of which will do 250 requests. I add each of these requests to the task list and call Task.WhenAll. Seems to work. Any objections to going about solving my problem this way?

Comment: This is a much better approach indeed. doing a lot with one client can pose a lot of limitations from the server.